# Similarity of seasons on Neptune and Earth

Tags: planetary-science

We all have basic ideas about planets and their seasons..But my question is that why do NEPTUNE and EARTH have similar seasons although their compositions are completely different..On earth Nitrogen dominates the atmosphere while on neptune Hydrogen dominates..Are seasons defined on axial tilt basis only?? Coz the axial tilt of earth is 23.5 and of neptune is 28.3( Both in degrees)..

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "similar season"? Are you asking about the fact that there is something like "northern winter", or asking about whether there is snow, or what is it?

Comment: I don't think Neptune is a good choice of planet. Why not edit your question to use Mars as an example, where the seasons are clearly visible and are in some respects Earth-like? It also has a very different atmosphere, if that's what you want.

Comment: Should think the gas really only affects the pace at redistribution of the energy obtained and any sidetracking reactivity.  Similar tilt = similar distribution of energy.  The orbital period is likely much more significant in the difference in seasons given each one lasts 41 years on Neptune, whereas one might argue they shift on Earth before being allowed to reach a steadier equilibrium.